How to evaluate this integral $\int_0^a x^{-v-3/2}(a-x)^{-v-1/2}[1-bx(a-x)]^vdx$
I need help to evaluate : $$I=\int_0^a x^{-v-3/2}(a-x)^{-v-1/2}[1-bx(a-x)]^vdx$$
This proplem in book Special Functions Derivatives, Integrals, Series and Other Formulas page 111 proplem 2
The answer is in the book.:
$$I=B(-v-1/2,1/2)\left({\frac{4}{a^2}-b}\right)^{v+1/2}$$
My attempt:
Let :$y=\frac{x}{a-x}\implies 
dx=\frac{a}{(1+y)^2}dy $
$$I=a^{-2v-1}\int_0^{\infty}y^{-v-3/2}(y^2+y(2-a^2b)+1)^vdy$$
Is there a way to evaluate this integration? I really appreciate your interest.

My solution
$$I=\int^{a}_{0}x^{-v-3/2}(a-x)^{-v-1/2}[1-bx(a-x)]^v dx$$
Let y=x/a
$$I=a^{-2v-1}\int^{1}_{0}y^{-v-3/2}(1-y)^{-v-1/2}[1-a^2by(1-y)]^v dy$$
$$I=a^{-2v-1}\int^{1}_{0}y^{-v-3/2}(1-y)^{-v-1/2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{v \choose n}(-a^2b)^ny^n(1-y)^n dy$$
$$\; =a^{-2v-1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{v \choose n}(-a^2b)^nB(n-v-1/2,n-v+1/2)$$
$$=a^{-2v-1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{v \choose n}(-a^2b)^n\frac{\Gamma{(n-v-1/2)}\Gamma{(n-v+1/2)}}{\Gamma{(2(n-v))}}$$
$$I=\sqrt{\pi}\frac{a^{-2v-1}}{2^{-2v-1}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{v \choose n}(-a^2b)^n\frac{\Gamma{(n-v-1/2)}}{2^{2n}\Gamma{(n-v)}}$$
we have :$$\frac{\Gamma{(n-v-1/2)}}{\Gamma{(n-v)}}=\frac{\Gamma{(-v-1/2)}}{\Gamma{(-v)}}\cdot \frac{(-v-1/2)_n}{(-v)_n}$$
and
$${v \choose n}=\frac{(-1)^n(-v)_n}{n!}$$
Therfore:
$$I=\sqrt{\pi}\frac{a^{-2v-1}}{2^{-2v-1}}\cdot \frac{\Gamma{(-v-1/2)}}{\Gamma{(-v)}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(-v)_n}{n!}(-a^2b)^n\frac{(-v-1/2)_n}{(-v)_n2^{2n}}$$
$$=\sqrt{\pi}\frac{a^{-2v-1}}{2^{-2v-1}}\cdot \frac{\Gamma{(-v-1/2)}}{\Gamma{(-v)}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-v-1/2)_n}{n!}\left({\frac{a^2b}{4}}\right)^n$$
$$=\sqrt{\pi}\frac{a^{-2v-1}}{2^{-2v-1}}\cdot \frac{\Gamma{(-v-1/2)}}{\Gamma{(-v)}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{v+1/2 \choose n}(-1)^n\left({\frac{a^2b}{4}}\right)^n$$
$$=\left({\frac{4}{a^2}}\right)^{v+1/2}B(-v-1/2,1/2)\left({1-\frac{a^2b}{4}}\right)^{v+1/2}$$
$$=B(-v-1/2,1/2)\left({\frac{4}{a^2}-b}\right)^{v+1/2}$$
